# optimal time series representation

Tags: mysql, time-series, partitioning, plc

I would like to know your opinion about the way of organizing my time series data in MySQL 5.6:
I am working in a project which needs to store data coming from different sensors. To be clear, we are monitoring several industrial facilities. Each one is controlled by a PLC device (or station), which locally stores the most relevant information for the process. Each sensor is mapped into a tag in the plc, and the plc periodically sends this information to an FTP server in CSV format. We chose innoDB as our storage engine, and the following tables are in place:

- `tbl_stations (id,name)`
- `tbl_tags (station_id, tag_id, name ... ) with (station_id, name) being the PK`
- `tbl_data (station_id, tag_id, time, value) with PK (stations_id, tag_id, time)`

The `PK` in `tbl_data` table is to allow for fast range queries of the form

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_data WHERE station=x and tag_id=y and time BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Also, because some tags are sampled very rapidly, the table `tbl_data` grows very quickly. In order to manage it better, and because we are normally accessing the most recent information, we partitioned `tbl_data` by range on the `"time"` column (which is a timestamp). In particular, we are using 4 partitions per year. Even with partitioning enabled, a single partition can grow a lot as the number of stations increases. So we decided to subpartition by station_id, in such a way that each subpartition would only contain the data for a few stations. In particular, we used HASH partitioning  for this purpose.

For the moment, everything works very well, but I just would like to hear from you just in case there is yet room for improvement. This is my first experience with time series data ... so it may be the case that I am missing something important.

I forgot to mention that we receive the data from each station in the following format:

```
TAG_ID1
TIME, VALUE
TIME, VALUE
.
.

TAG_ID2
TIME, VALUE
TIME, VALUE
.
.
.
```

and so on. This way, the insertions are somehow in `PK` order, which is good for getting fast insertion ratios as long as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to look at three things:

1. Do you need high-res historic data? If not, you should look into RRD-type databases that aggregate old data or implement data aggregation your self (e.g. the volkszaehler.org project has a `vzcompress` tool for doing so on time-series data). .
2. Do you often need to retrieve aggregated time series data (e.g. sums per day)? If yes a separate aggregate table might help like e.g. the volkszaehler.org project is implementing.
3. Your index with highest selectivity is probably timestamp, not station or tag. It might pay off to rebuild the order of your indexes, however I'm not sure and would recommend performance (=load) testing.

Comment: Many thanks for  your reply @andig. Regarding point 3, don't you think it is better to use (tag, time) index for time range queries? (as in my query example above)

Comment: I honestly don't know. I've read highest-selectivity first but would suggest specifically asking int he DBA forum. Interested in the answer myself ;)

Comment: I already found several forums where this issue is explained. It seems that the right order (for better performance in time range queries) would be fist "tag", then "time". I think this issue is also explained in the book "Effective Mysql. Optimizing Sql Statements (Oracle Press)".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't addressed any SQL questions, but I'm answering the "room for improvement" question.

I would suggest you manually compress the data based on your own requirements.  While RRD mentioned is good for fixed-size data files, it's no good if you want to keep data for an unspecified amount of time, or use the features of your SQL server to archive the data.

What we did is use a max-delta algorithm, whereby each trend (temperature, voltage, etc.) had it's own dv (change in value) and dt (change in time) stored in some metadata for each trend, such that if `measured dv < required dv`, we didn't store a new sample, and similarly if the `measured dt < required dt`.

This gave us great compression and flexibility, as you typically don't get much variability in temperature readings (set dv=0.5 and dt=30s); whereas you need high resolution for voltage (set dv=0.01 and dt=0) etc.

The disadvantages of this method came in trending and analysis.  Since we wrote our own tools for this the most difficult ones to overcome were:

1. how do you represent a curve between two points that haven't changed for x seconds: as a straight line between the points? This would imply that the value was linear.  In the end we used a step-line, so the value remained the same until a new value was received.
2. how do you detect offline periods or comms problems? Since you no longer have an implicit heartbeat of one sample every poll, we had to introduce another metadata trend which showed that the data was valid even though the value wasn't changing for some amount of time, or similarly that the data was invalid in certain sections.

The end result was that we could record some trends for a number of years with small storage sizes even though there was a high poll rate.